# Simple HTML Dom Strange Behaviour with Previous Sibling

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl, simple-html-dom

I am scraping this URL [enter link description here](https://horsforthhp.play-cricket.com/Matches?tab=Fixture)for cricket fixtures.  The project is to push all the content into an array so I can reformat for various projects including publishing to images for social media and a digital display board in the club house.

The HTML div for the fixture date prefixes multiple fixtures, so I have used `->prev_Sibling()` to obtain;

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$fixtures = array();
$html = str_get_html($file_contents);
foreach($html->find('div.match-tbc div.card-table') as $card){
  $prev = $card->prev_Sibling();
  $prev = $prev->innertext;
  $fixtures[] = $prev;
  echo $prev;
  echo $card;
 }
```

The problem I am having is that when I push `$fixtures[] = $prev;` to an array, the content isn't just the date from the site as I would expect, it grabs all the data from the $table fixtures as well.

I have tried `$prev->plaintext;` and `$prev->innertext;` and still I cannot obtain just the date.

[image: Array Output]

This is a snapshot of the HTML;

[image]

Comment: There are several `.card-table` elements in succession, so if you go back to the previous sibling for each one - then you are only going to get that date containing element for the first of those `.card-table` elements - for the following ones, you of course get the previous `.card-table` element.